# Issue with SimpMessagingTemplate not sending socket message to client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a web application that uses Kafka and Spring WebSocket for emitting different events to a mobile app. Events are triggered based on the logic where mobile app is online or offline.

The logic works perfectly fine if an event is triggered when mobile app is already online. But if it's offline, the triggered event is stored in a postgres table and marked with status PENDING. So when the mobile app comes back online, these table searches for the message and then triggers the event.

In order to update the mobile status, I am using Socket Sessions, and ChannelInterceptor which updates the mobile app status on SUBSCRIBE and DISCONNECT event.

I have logs at every possible place, and all the logs are executed when the mobile app comes back online. There's no error anywhere. The last log is right before :

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser();
```

Logs :

```
Device Status in request : true
Send Mode : IMMEDIATE
inside immediate never expire >>>>> 
Enter: SocketService.send() with argument[s] = [{Status=200, Response={PayloadId=1415, PayloadExpiryDateTime=0, PayloadPriority=1, EventType=NEW_MESSAGE, TemporaryMessage={Messages={Data=[{Title=Message1, DataToSend={Message=Message1, Data=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, ReqNr=9.0000001E7}}]}, Playlists={Data=[{Title=TemporaryPlaylist, DataToSend={Message=Temporary Playlist, Data=G7Prf2ZRUh+MSBNTjLH2BT7nNB1o8zXgz/mn9leZ7Q4UoZH1MzMrJj3ISvdkQZNAbVCnYQjh5XhOnUr1kGrZpWJ/lHUyJi1coc7fdMxe0fkgBJk9SySvaFN/TvFQaUlv2wRWIoPVXmLVhukFgzLsDeVWmuzNaWZXTQCemIzrK6SaCJ+FfFAzgxG2Z7QxWkVx, ReqNr=9.0000002E7}}]}, ShowCommands={Data=[{DataToSend={Type=ShowPlaylistRequest, ShowAll=[{CallWord=t2212161322}]}}]}}}, Message=Success}, message, 108]
Sending to Producer : {"Status":200,"Response":{"PayloadId":1415,"PayloadExpiryDateTime":0,"PayloadPriority":1,"EventType":"NEW_MESSAGE","TemporaryMessage":{"Messages":{"Data":[{"Title":"Message1","DataToSend":{"Message":"Message1","Data":"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","ReqNr":9.0000001E7}}]},"Playlists":{"Data":[{"Title":"TemporaryPlaylist","DataToSend":{"Message":"Temporary Playlist","Data":"G7Prf2ZRUh+MSBNTjLH2BT7nNB1o8zXgz/mn9leZ7Q4UoZH1MzMrJj3ISvdkQZNAbVCnYQjh5XhOnUr1kGrZpWJ/lHUyJi1coc7fdMxe0fkgBJk9SySvaFN/TvFQaUlv2wRWIoPVXmLVhukFgzLsDeVWmuzNaWZXTQCemIzrK6SaCJ+FfFAzgxG2Z7QxWkVx","ReqNr":9.0000002E7}}]},"ShowCommands":{"Data":[{"DataToSend":{"Type":"ShowPlaylistRequest","ShowAll":[{"CallWord":"t2212161322"}]}}]}}},"Message":"Success"}
Exit: SocketService.send() with result = null
Received from Kafka : {"Status":200,"Response":{"PayloadId":1415,"PayloadExpiryDateTime":0,"PayloadPriority":1,"EventType":"NEW_MESSAGE","TemporaryMessage":{"Messages":{"Data":[{"Title":"Message1","DataToSend":{"Message":"Message1","Data":"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","ReqNr":9.0000001E7}}]},"Playlists":{"Data":[{"Title":"TemporaryPlaylist","DataToSend":{"Message":"Temporary Playlist","Data":"G7Prf2ZRUh+MSBNTjLH2BT7nNB1o8zXgz/mn9leZ7Q4UoZH1MzMrJj3ISvdkQZNAbVCnYQjh5XhOnUr1kGrZpWJ/lHUyJi1coc7fdMxe0fkgBJk9SySvaFN/TvFQaUlv2wRWIoPVXmLVhukFgzLsDeVWmuzNaWZXTQCemIzrK6SaCJ+FfFAzgxG2Z7QxWkVx","ReqNr":9.0000002E7}}]},"ShowCommands":{"Data":[{"DataToSend":{"Type":"ShowPlaylistRequest","ShowAll":[{"CallWord":"t2212161322"}]}}]}}},"Message":"Success"}
Sending to Socket Client.......
```

But the front-end never gets the message.

Below are some code snippets:

Channel Interceptor:

```
public class SocketInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    SocketSessionService socketSessionService;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = headers.get(StompHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS,MultiValueMap.class);

        if (multiValueMap !=null) {
            if (multiValueMap.containsKey("destination")) {
                String destination = multiValueMap.get("destination").get(0);
                log.info("Destination in interceptor : " + destination);
            }
        }

        if (accessor.getCommand()!=null) {
            log.info("Client Method : " + accessor.getCommand().name());
            if (accessor.getCommand().equals(StompCommand.CONNECT) || accessor.getCommand().equals(StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE) || accessor.getCommand().equals(StompCommand.SEND)) {
                if (!multiValueMap.containsKey("access-token")) {
                    log.error("Token Error " + "No Token was provided in + " + accessor.getCommand().name());
                    throw new MessagingException("Forbidden: No Token was provided in header for Socket Command: " + accessor.getCommand().name());
                }
                String token = multiValueMap.get("access-token").get(0);
                if (JwtTokenUtil.verifyToken(JwtTokenUtil.decrypt(token))) {
                    log.info("Token Verified Successfully >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ");

                    Claims claims = JwtTokenUtil.verifyJwtToken(JwtTokenUtil.decrypt(token));
                    accessor.setHeader("access-token", token);
                    Principal principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims.getId(), null, null);

                    accessor.setUser(principal);
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            claims.getId(), null, null);


                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                    if (accessor.getCommand().equals(StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE)){
                        log.info("Storing Socket Session on Socket Command SUBSCRIBE ");
                        SocketSessionModel model=new SocketSessionModel();
                        model.setSessionId(accessor.getSessionId());
                        model.setDeviceId(multiValueMap.get("destination").get(0));
                        model.setAccessToken(token);
                        model.setCurrentStatus(SocketSessionStatus.ONLINE);
                        model.setReportedOnlineAt(ZonedDateTime.now().with(ZoneOffset.UTC));
                        model.setReportedOfflineAt(null);
                        socketSessionService.onSubscribe(model);
                    }
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
                    try {
                        log.info("Returning back the frame : " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message.getPayload()));
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new GenericMessage<>(message.getPayload(), accessor.getMessageHeaders());
                }
                throw new MessagingException("Token either Expired or Invalid");
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

WebSocket Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    SocketSessionService socketSessionService;

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {

        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/user")
                .setTaskScheduler(customTaskScheduler())
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{25000,10000});
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(socketInterceptor());
    }
    @Bean
    public SocketInterceptor socketInterceptor() {
        return new SocketInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler customTaskScheduler(){
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @EventListener(SessionDisconnectEvent.class)
    public void handleWsDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        Optional<String> sessionId= getSessionIdFromEvent(event);
        sessionId.ifPresent(s -> socketSessionService.onDisconnect(s));
    }
    private Optional<String> getSessionIdFromEvent(AbstractSubProtocolEvent event) {
        String sessionId = null;
        System.out.println("Session Id in event : " + (event.getMessage().getHeaders()).get("simpSessionId"));
        Object sessionIdAsObject = (event.getMessage().getHeaders()).get("simpSessionId");
        if (nonNull(sessionIdAsObject) && sessionIdAsObject.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            sessionId = (String) sessionIdAsObject;
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionId) ? null : sessionId);
    }
}
```

Kafka Producer Config :

```
@Service
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Async
    public void send(String data, String kafkaTopic, String key) {

        kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, key, data);
    }

    @Async
    public void send(String topic, String data ){
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data);
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumer Config :

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> rawKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("something"));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Kafka Listener :
This is the last step where socket emits the messages to clients. The last line of log mentioned here is executed.

```
@Component
public class KafkaListenerForSocket {

    private final Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListenerForSocket.class);

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @KafkaListener(topics = KafkaTopicConstants.MESSAGE, containerFactory = "rawKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenToMessages(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        String destination="/queue/message";
        BaseSocketResponse response=objectMapper.readValue(consumerRecord.value(), BaseSocketResponse.class);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(consumerRecord.key(),destination,response);

    }

    public void send(Object data, String key){
        log.info("Bypassing Kafka and sending directly");
        String destination="/queue/message";
        log.info("sending to destination : " + "/user/"+key+destination);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(key, destination, data);
    }
}
```

BaseSocketResponse.Java class :

```
public class BaseSocketResponse<T> {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Status", required = true)
    private Integer status;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Message", required = true)
    private String statusMessage = "";

    @JsonProperty(value = "Response", required = true)
    private T response;


    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }

    public T getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(T response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

}
```

front-end code :

```
var stompClient = null;

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#userinfo").html("");
}

function connect() {
    let header={"access-token" : $("#token").val()};
    var socket = new SockJS('/services/toplight/ws');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect(header, function (frame) {
        if(frame.command == "CONNECTED") {
            console.log("Inside frame command : >>>>> " + frame);
            setConnected(true);
            subscribe(stompClient)
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Inside Connect error : " + error );
        onConnectError(error);
    });
}

function subscribe(stompClient){
    
    var token=$("#token").val();
    var header={"access-token": token};

console.log("Subscribing to Destination : " + '/user/'+$("#name").val()+'/queue/message');
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/'+$("#name").val()+'/queue/message' , greeting, header);

    var greeting=function(message){
        var body=JSON.parse(message.body);
        if(body.Response.EventType=="NEW_MESSAGE"){
            showNewMessage(response);
        }
    
        if(body.Response.EventType=="DEVICE_UPDATE_RESPONSE"){
            showDeviceUpdate(response);
        }
    
        if(body.Response.EventType=="MESSAGE_UPDATE_RESPONSE"){
            showMessageUpdate(response);
        }    
    };

}

function onConnectError(error){
    console.log("Error : >>>>> " + error);
    $("#greetings").append("<h3><tr><td>" + error + "</h3>");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any client acknowledgement from frontend or is it auto acknowledgement? How do you receive the message. Can you post that too.

Comment: What is the message broker that you are using with websocket?

Comment: @pacman client doesn't receive the message at all. But on the Java side, every single line of code is executed without any error.

Kafka with Zookeeper as message broker

Comment: Can you try to see if the messages are send to same queue that you are expecting to? How does the subscribed queue name look from frontend and its corresponding name from backend? Also please post the subscription code at frontend

Comment: @pacman yes, I have "destination" logged on the front as well as on the java side to make sure I am sending it to correct destination. which is "/user/<userId>/queue/message"... updating my question with the front-end code.

Comment: All the logs work fine, if the device_status is online.... But if device is offline, any message triggered by admin is stored in a postgres table, and when the device comes back online, these messages are picked up and then send to that device. This is where the code fails.

Comment: Do you have a custom handshake handler? How do you get `key` in `messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(key, destination, data);`.

Comment: @pacman I have a channelInterceptor, which gets the destination, and I extract the key from there. Updating that code too in the question.

Comment: So the key remains same at all times? The claims.getId() won't change during reconnect or after sometime?

Comment: No, it's the unique device ID, which is sent by the mobile app. Every mobile app is connected to only 1 device at a time. Every device ID is further mapped to a unique Device Serial number. So mobile app doesn't have access to other device serial UIDs

Comment: Can you try one experiment. Can you directly inject the data to queue without using `SimpMessagingTemplate` and see if you get data in the frontend during reconnect?

Comment: @pacman not sure how to inject directly in queue ? Any guideline please ?

Comment: If you are using rabbitmq then use AmpqTemplate or if with activemq JmsTemplate.

Comment: I am using none. There's  Kafka producer and consumer in the same java web back-end...

Comment: Kafka is not message broker for stomp websocket. You are using it for different purpose. Currently you are using inbuilt queue in java by default which is not recommended for production. In the `WebsocketConfig` class in the method `configureMessageBroker` you have to configure it. Currently it is `        config.enableSimpleBroker("/user")` which is the inbuilt queue. You need to run activemq artemis or rabbitmq or something like that in your local and  configure it here.

Comment: What I did now is configure an outbound channel interceptor and logged every message that's send. I also have an inbound interceptor. 

What I noticed that, if a user = 10, is online, and I send a message... it's delivered. But if user is offline, the message is stored in table. Next time when user 10 comes online, inbound intercetpor calls my method to mark user as online, and then that message takes all the messages for that user and triggers them. These messages are not logged in outbound channel. Same message are logged, if user is online and msg is sent.